# Cannot connect to network from inside Virtualbox (Windows Host, Gentoo Guest)

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, bridge, gentoo

I recently got my computer upgraded from windows 8 to 10, and since then, I've been having trouble getting the internet to work.  I was hoping that someone could give me some advice on how to debug this issue...I'm not incredibly knowledgeable about networking so I'm afraid I don't know how to look for this next.

Note that the "upgrade" was really a fresh install on a new computer, and then a move of the virtual machine, so there's probably an incompatibility somewhere that's silently failing.  Nothing significant (I think) has changed on the guest.

Currently I can ping anything both in and out of the network (and correctly have dns resolve the ip address) but I am unable to connect to anything through a web browser or with ssh).

Switching to NAT causes everything to work okay, but I would really like to be able to connect back to my virtual machine from outside.

Here's all the relevant settings I can think of:

```
Host:  Windows 10
Guest:  Gentoo Linux
Virtualbox Version:  5.0.18r106667
```

**Virtualbox Network Settings**

```
Adapter 1
Attached to:  Bridged Adapter
Name:  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM (This is the only option)
Adapter Type:  Intel PRO/100 MT Desktop (82540EM)
Promiscuous Mode:  Deny
MAC Address: 08002773B4D5
Cable Connected:  Yes
```

**Guest Network Settings**

```
enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:73:b4:d5 brc ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.11.59/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
valid_lft 172062sec preferred_lft 172062sec
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe73:b4d5/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

(lo is up and sit0@NONE is down, if it makes any difference)
```

**Windows Network Settings**

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix .... <redacted for privacy>
Link-local IPv6 Address ... fe80::f425::99b3:dd28:dee6%4
IPv4 Address ... 192.168.11.170
Subnet Mask ... 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway ... 192.168.11.254
```

Let me know what other information I can give.  I appreciate any advice you can give!

Note:  `ping www.google.com` works, but `telnet www.google.com 80` doesn't.

Note2:  Running wireshark on the host while trying to telnet is just showing DNS protocol queries and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my firewall was blocking traffic from other IPs, and I need to add an exception to the firewall.

Comment: Might help to add which firewall - host or guest...

Comment: Sorry!  It was my host's firewall.